# Use 'JOIN' to select top five records from a table that match a specific column in table two

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two table:

```
Audit
AUDITID |  CUSTOMER  |  CUSTOMERNUMBER
001     |    BILLY   |  11111 
002     |    HOLLY   |  12222 
003     |    HOLLY   | 12222
004     |    DON     | 13333
005     |    DON     | 13333

Summary
AuditID | Summary | Date
001     |  1      |   30/1/2012
001     |  2      | 1/10/2012
001     | 3       |20/10/2012
004     | 4       | 2/09/2012
004     | 5       | 3/01/2012
```

I want to select the top five records table for each different AuditID that matches an Audit ID From the Audit table.

The sql script i have so far is :

```
    SELECT Auditid, summary, date
    FROM [Summary] SL1
    INNER JOIN [Audit] AL1 ON SL1.[AuditID] = AL1.[AuditID]  
    WHERE AL1.[AuditID] IN (  
    SELECT TOP 5 AuditID  
    FROM [Audit] AL2  
    WHERE AL1.[CustomerNumber] = AL2.[CustomerNumber]   
    ORDER BY AL2.[AuditID] DESC
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Auditid, summary, date,
      ,  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SL1.AuditID ORDER BY SL1.Date ASC)
    FROM [Summary] SL1
    INNER JOIN [Audit] AL1 ON SL1.[AuditID] = AL1.[AuditID]  
)
SELECT Auditid, summary, date FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 5
```

That returns the TOP 5 records for each AuditID ordered by Date(oldest first, use `DESC` otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which order you want the "top" records from summary - I chose to do it by summary, you can do by date or something. Also I did top2 to show results using your sample data.

```
select audit.auditid,Summary,DATE 
from 
    Audit inner join Summary Sum_Tab1 on Audit.AUDITID=Sum_Tab1.AUDITID 
where 
    Sum_Tab1.SUMMARY in 
        (SELECT top 2 SUMMARY from Summary Sum_Tab2 
            where Sum_Tab1.AUDITID=Sum_Tab2.AUDITID order by summary)
```